# mongodb second id field with auto increment

Tags: mongodb, auto-increment

I want to have an additional ID field in my mongodb collection.
The objectId is perfect for get unique IDs, but I need shorter IDs for my user management. These IDs should look like `100001`, `100002` and so on. Is it possible to get these by auto increment?

Thx

Comment: Have you solved the puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not have an auto increment functionality.

You could solve this by keeping track the 'id' in a separate collection called 'user_sequence' and store a custom function in MongoDB to get the next value.

Take a look at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Create a query like:

```
db.users.insert({
    userid: sequenceNextValue("userid")
})
```

Step by step tutorial by MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/